# “specified child already has a parent” error

Tags: android, layout

Sorry to make another topic on this subjcet but I've already read several of them and still don't know why I'm getting this error. I followed the "Building Your First App" tutorial on http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html and then tried to modify my application to give a layout to DisplayMessageActivity Class. I've created a file called "activity_displaymessage.xml" and implemented it to the class.

I'm new to android and I'm trying to understand how this all works. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.sampleandroid.MESSAGE";

        .
        .
        .


    public void sendMessage(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_displaymessage);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        textview.setText(message);

        setContentView(textview);
    }
}
```

activity_displaymessage.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `setContentView`.Your layout file `activity_displaymessage` have already child view `R.id.text_view` then why are you set it as setContentView().

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_displaymessage);` and  `setContentView(textview);`

**Remove this line `setContentView(textview);`**

Answer (score 1):

When you do a setContentView(), the view passed to it gets attached to the parent. In your case, text_view's parent is already getting set when you call

> setContentView(R.layout.activity_displaymessage)

In the last line when you try to setContentView(textview), what basically happens is that the same object which u get using (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view) is being assigned a parent when it already has a parent. This is not allowed and hence the error.

You don't need the last line.